# ¿Es posible ver las preguntas que se han eliminado en las que habías respondido?

Tags: soporte, eliminación-de-preguntas, eliminación-de-respuestas, búsqueda

Hoy me ha surgido una duda viendo una pregunta que encaja perfectamente a una respuesta que di hace bastante tiempo a una pregunta similar.

Cuando la he ido a buscar para marcarla como duplicada, no la he podido encontrar de ninguna manera, por lo que he pensado que igual podría ser que la hubieran borrado hace poco (la vi hace menos de dos semanas pero ahora me es imposible encontrarla).

La duda que me ha surgido es, en todas aquellas preguntas en las que hemos respondido y después han sido eliminadas, ¿hay alguna forma de verlas? ¿o si se elimina la pregunta se elimina definitivamente?

De esta manera me sería mucho más fácil saber si la pregunta a la que respondí ha sido borrada o sigue en activo y por lo tanto estoy haciendo mal la búsqueda.

Comment: Es difícil que haya sido eliminada, aún más si esta se marco como respuesta aceptada. A mi me sucede lo mismo, en ocasiones no encuentro la pregunta :-|, pero es principalmente porque la pregunta no tiene un titulo adecuado.

Comment: @Jorgesys Sí, pienso que es eso porque el otro día la vi y me ha sido imposible encontrarla de ninguna manera, ni en las eliminadas ni en las no eliminadas. Debe ser que por el día de todos los santos se ha convertido en "pregunta fantasma" :P Seguro que cuando menos quiera encontrármela, la vuelvo a encontrar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes buscarlas cuando tienes reputación mayor a 10K:

```
user:me is:answer deleted:yes
```

Y a continuación más condiciones, del tipo:

- `score:X` para la puntuación que tiene (`..-2`, `2`, etc)
- `[etiqueta1] -[etiqueta2]` si tenía [etiqueta1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/etiqueta1) pero no [etiqueta2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/etiqueta2)
- `created:2017`
- etc

Comment: Excelente respuesta, desconocía totalmente como hacer dicha consulta y considerando que estoy próximo a los 10k lo aplicaré, +1 además está debería ser la respuesta aceptada

Comment: Yo también estoy próximo a los 10K, ¡qué ganas ya de llegar! :D

Comment: Wow! Muchisimas gracias!! Es justo lo que andaba buscando :)

Answer (score 3):

Me parece que:

- Si la pregunta fue eliminada por el autor, pero no por motivos de moderación entonces aquellos usuarios que tengan una reputación mayor o igual a 10000 podrán acceder a ella siempre y cuando tengan el enlace.

Hasta donde se la pregunta solo pudo haber sido eliminada si:

- No tiene respuestas aceptadas
- Las respuestas dadas no tienen suficientes votos positivos

Los puntos anteriores los menciono por qué por ejemplo si yo público una pregunta y al ser respondida por alguien y esa respuesta recibe positivos yo ya no podré eliminar mi publicación pues el sistema dice algo parecido a: **No puedes eliminar esto pues otros usuarios han dedicado esfuerzo en responder**

Comment: Entonces según esto debería seguir disponible... Mmm... la buscaré más a fondo a ver si finalmente la encuentro. Muchas gracias por toda la info :)

Comment: Por otro lado, si la ha eliminado el autor entiendo que no hay ninguna manera de descubrirlo sin tener el enlace a la misma no? Osea ningún opción que te aparezcan tus respuestas eliminadas o algo así.

Comment: De hecho si se puede checa la query provista en la lo otra respuesta